# HQL запрос по внешнему ключу

Tags: java, spring-boot, hql

Имеется две таблицы PersonEntity и CityEntity. PersonEntity в БД связана с CityEntity внешним ключем fk_cityid.
Мне необходимо выбрать все записи (имена) таблицы PersonEntity с заданным cityId. Везде для этого используют join, но в данном случае мне не нужны данные из таблицы CityEntity, только поле name таблицы PersonEntity.
Вот описание классов:

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private CityEntity cityId;
}
@Entity
public class CityEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Вот HQL запрос:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
  @Query("select p.name FROM PersonEntity p where (p.name = :name or :name is null) " +
        "and (p.cityId = :cityId or :cityId is null)")
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndCity (
        @Param("name") String name,
        @Param("cityId") CityEntity cityId);
}
```

пробовал по id:

```
 @Query("select p.name FROM PersonEntity p where (p.name = :name or :name is null) " +
        "and (p.cityId.id = :cityId or :cityId is null)")
    List<PersonEntity> findByNameAndCity (
        @Param("name") String name,
        @Param("cityId") Long cityId);
```

В обоих случаях ошибка: не удалось определить тип данных.

Comment: Это CityEntity, исправил

Comment: HQL не поддерживает тип данных table

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, в запросе запрашивается всего одно поле `name`, а на выходе надо получить список `Person`.

Или получай список `String`, или запрашивай `p`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте в ответе вопросительных формулировок. Или вы даёте ответ, или, если вы в нём не уверены, напишите комментарий.